# Как исправить ошибку-'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: django

```
class forms
 from django import forms
 from django.contrib.auth.models import User
 from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
 from accounts.models import UserProfile


class RegistrationForm (UserCreationForm):
 email = forms.EmailField(required = True)

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username',
              'first_name',
              'last_name',
              'email',
              'password1',
              'password2'
              )
    def save (self, commit= True):
        user = super(RegistrationForm,self).save(commit=True)
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        # user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])


        if commit:
            user.save()

        return user

 class RegistrationFormFull (UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
       model = UserProfile
       fields = ('city',
              'discription',
              'phone'
              )




   //class views
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.shortcuts import redirect
    from welcome.form import RegistrationForm,RegistrationFormFull
    from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
    from django.db import transaction
    from accounts.models import UserProfile
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User


    def register (request) :
     if request.method == 'POST':
       user_form = RegistrationForm(request.POST,instance=request.User)
       full_form = 
        RegistrationFormFull(request.POST,instance=request.User.UserProfile)
        if user_form.is_valid() and full_form.is_valid():
         user_form.save()
         full_form.save()
         return redirect('/home')

   else:
     user_form = RegistrationForm(instance=request.user)
     full_form = RegistrationFormFull(instance=request.UserProfile)
     args = {'user_form':user_form,
             'full_form':full_form
            }
     return  render(request,'welcome/reg_form.html',args)
```

Comment: Отформатируйте код и добавьте к вопросу полный текст ошибки.

Answer (score 1):

Никак. Просто проверяйте авторизирован ли пользователь в системе, предварительно.